# Unpack symfony/symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I started working in a huge project written in Symfony which is at version 2.8. Upgrading the whole project to SF 3 would take hundreds of hours and it's not possible right now. I came up with an idea to unpack `symfony/symfony` package to single packages it replaces (key `replace` in `composer.json`). It would unlock all 45 packages that are locked on `self.version` and allow us to upgrade any package step by step if possible.

**Example:** I have `doctrine/orm` locked at `2.5.*` and cannot ugrade to `2.6` (what will get rid of few bugs and also allow me to upgrade PHP `7.2` --> `7.3`) because I have `symfony/console` locked by `symfony/symfony` at version `2.8` and `doctrine/orm:2.6` requires `symfony/console:~3.0.0`. However my project would allow to have `symfony/console` even at version `^3.2` so you can see my point.

**I would like to ask you if there are any dangers to the application when attempting to unpack `symfony/symfony`?** So far I can't see any.

P.S. Info for those how want to answer "just require a single package with higher version". Since Composer 1.7.3 it's not possible and will trigger a version conflict.

Comment: I never had much luck with doing those sorts of things with composer but that is probably just because of lack of skill on my part.  But Symfony 3 removes Symfony 2 depreciated code.  So if you are still getting notices then I suspect you will run into plenty of issues.  If you don't have notices then upgrading to 3.4 should be straight forward.  What makes you expect that it will take hundreds of hours?  Third party bundles?

Answer (score 0):

In such case it will be better to walk in a tiny steps and carefully check results of each step. Of course if whole your project is covered by tests it would be much simpler to do such change, but I don't know if it is.

I would probably do something like this:

1. Copy `composer.json` into separate directory
2. Get exact versions of packages by running `composer info`
3. Look into list of packages provided by `symfony/symfony` e.g. by looking into [its own](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/composer.json#L36-L81) `composer.json` or by looking at [its page](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony#2.8.x-dev) on Packagist.
4. Replace `symfony/symfony` in copied `composer.json` with individual packages of same versions as you currently have.
5. Run `composer install` and compare resulted set of actually installed packages with packages installed for your project. Simplest way is to compare output of `composer info` from both directories. You can also use something like `composer info | awk -F ' ' '{print $1 " " $2}' | sort` to get sorted list of packages and their versions so it will be easier to compare.
6. Tune packages list and version constraints until you will achieve same results from `composer info` for both actual project and your new `composer.json`.
7. Copy `composer.json` back into main project. By this time you will be able to install same vendor packages but will be able to control them separately.
8. Go on with package versions tuning but don't forget to apply minimal changes at a time and test (hopefully by running auto-tests) each change separately.

I hope you know `composer why` command that allows you to examine package dependencies so you will understand better which packages will get affected by changing version of some particular package.

Good luck with this task because careful upgrade may take quite some time.